# Do the openssl X509_verify_cert() verifies the signature in the certificate?

Tags: c, linux, openssl

Do the openssl [X509_verify_cert()](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/X509_verify_cert.html) API verifies the RSA signature in the certificate ?

To my understanding , that API checks only certificate validity (like date check and all).

Somebody please clarify ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`X509_verify_cert()` essentially checks a certificate's validity. That includes verifying that signatures that have signed the cert belonging to CAs are valid and are in date - it'll process the entire chain like that.

It does not, however, verify that a given RSA signature is valid - although it validates RSA signatures as part of its work, it isn't what you should use to do that.

It is, broadly speaking, like the functionality that runs when you get a certificate error browsing an SSL site.

Answer (score 5):

API  X509_verify_cert()  verifies based on the Verification flag u set in the X509_store structure .
With this API u can verify the Certificate 
1.Expiry
2.Issuer (Trust path) 
2.1 Intermediate certificates Expiry ,
2.2 Intermediate certificates Trust chain ,
2.3 Intermediate certificates Revocation ,
3.Revocation of the Certificate against the CRL
3.1 CRL expiry
3.2 CRL Trust path
(Note : verify the CRL u need minimum one Certificate atleast in the store_ctx variable)
4.Depth of the Trust chain
5.Signature of the Certificates

Flags for different verification were mentioned in the x509_vfy.h file

```
        /* Send issuer+subject checks to verify_cb */
       #define  X509_V_FLAG_CB_ISSUER_CHECK     0x1
      /* Use check time instead of current time */
       #define  X509_V_FLAG_USE_CHECK_TIME      0x2
      /* Lookup CRLs */
      #define   X509_V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK           0x4
        /* Lookup CRLs for whole chain */
      #define   X509_V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK_ALL       0x8
        /* Ignore unhandled critical extensions */
      #define   X509_V_FLAG_IGNORE_CRITICAL     0x10
     /* Disable workarounds for broken certificates */
     #define    X509_V_FLAG_X509_STRICT         0x20
     /* Enable proxy certificate validation */
      #define   X509_V_FLAG_ALLOW_PROXY_CERTS       0x40
      /* Enable policy checking */
        #define X509_V_FLAG_POLICY_CHECK        0x80
     /* Policy variable require-explicit-policy */
   #define X509_V_FLAG_EXPLICIT_POLICY      0x100
    /* Policy variable inhibit-any-policy */
    #define X509_V_FLAG_INHIBIT_ANY         0x200
     /* Policy variable inhibit-policy-mapping */
      #define X509_V_FLAG_INHIBIT_MAP           0x400
    /* Notify callback that policy is OK */
     #define X509_V_FLAG_NOTIFY_POLICY      0x800
     /* Extended CRL features such as indirect CRLs, alternate CRL signing keys */
     #define X509_V_FLAG_EXTENDED_CRL_SUPPORT   0x1000
    /* Delt1a CRL support */
    #define X509_V_FLAG_USE_DELTAS          0x2000
     /* Check selfsigned CA signature */
   #define X509_V_FLAG_CHECK_SS_SIGNATURE       0x4000
```